# Second Level Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have Locations, Order and Event Models.

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :event
    validates :first_name, presence: true
    validates :last_name, presence: true
    validates :amount, presence: true, :numericality => {:only_integer=>true, :greater_than =>0}

end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :location
    validates :title, presence: true
    validates :price, presence: true, :numericality => {:greater_than =>0}

end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :events, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :orders, through: :events
    validates :title, presence: true
    validates :size, presence: true, :numericality => {:only_integer=>true,:greater_than =>0}
end
```

I want to check, in the orders `create` controller, how many seats the location has.

`@orders.events` returns me the right event. 
if I ask for `@order.event.location` the return is always `"#"`.

Is this a security issue? I also added in the `Location` model:

```
has_many: orders, through: events
```

Comment: Can you share your files?

Comment: `OrdersController

def create
  @order = Order.new(order_params)
  @location = Order.event.location
end
`

Comment: I posted the models here -> http://pastebin.com/Q49XZhAL

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hmm... standard stuff. Could you copy/paste your controller code as well? Because the one in your comment doesn't look right (`@location = Order.event.location`). I believe you did not copy/paste it from your actual code.